# Different AES Encryption results in PHP and JAVA

Tags: java, php, android-studio, encryption, aes

I have implemented two functions for Encryption/Decryption of data
transferred between server (PHP) and client (Android Application).
although both keys are the same, but I get completely different results
from the functions. What is the problem?

JAVA (Android Studio functions):

```
public static String encryptString(String string, String key){
    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(string.getBytes());
        return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.URL_SAFE);
    } catch(Exception e){
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}

private static String decryptString(String string, String key){
    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(string.getBytes());
        return Base64.decode(decrypted, Base64.DEFAULT ).toString();

    } catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

And PHP functions:

```
function fnEncrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey){
return rtrim(
    base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            $sSecretKey, $sValue, 
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
            mcrypt_create_iv(
                mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                    MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
            ), 
            MCRYPT_RAND)
        )
    ), "\0"
);
}

function fnDecrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey){
return rtrim(
    mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
        $sSecretKey, 
        base64_decode($sValue), 
        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
        mcrypt_create_iv(
            mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
            ), 
            MCRYPT_RAND
        )
    ), "\0"
);
}
```

Comment: ECB is not secure.  Do not use it.

Comment: Textual characters do not have enough entropy to create useful keys.  Use secure random bytes, or at least a KDF.

Comment: In short, using raw crypto primitives securely is _hard_.  http://blog.slaks.net/2015-11-18/common-crypto-pitfalls/ Don't do this.  Use libraries like libsodium or keyczar instead.

Comment: Returning exception messages as ciphertext is a horrible idea.

Comment: The Initialization Vector (IV) used for decryption must be the same as the IV generated during encryption. I'm not a PHP expert, but I don't see that happening. Since the IV is *not* a secret, a common convention is to prepend it to the cyphertext and strip it off when decrypting.

Comment: @SLaks The problem with libsodium is that it supports a small set of encryption options so interopeability is very poor or nonexistent. Sure it is good if you can run it on both sides.

Comment: Getting encryption security correct is like brain surgery, you don't go to a General Practitioner for brain surgery you go to a Brain Surgeon. In a similar manner e general developer generally should not attempt to create secure encryption, the possibility of errors that defeat security are just to large. One small mistake such as returning a padding error when using CBC mode can allow an attacker to obtain the plain text without knowing the key.

Comment: At a minimum get a cryptographic domain expert (SME) to help with the design and review the code, I do. These people are many times called "Despicable SMEs" because they keep saying "You can't do that."

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell what the default options (padding, mode) are when they are not explicitly specified in the initialization string: `Cipher.getInstance("AES")`.

AES has a block size of 128.bits so you need to specift that to mcrypt: MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128. MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is not AES.

A reaonable assumption is that the Java is using PKCS#5 (actually PKCS#7 for AES) padding. mcrypt however does not support PKCS#5 (or PKCS#7) padding, only null padding and null padding can not be used for binary data.

The best solution is to explicitly specify the Java padding and mode, the php code specifies ECB (which is not secure). The Java string probably should be: "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (128)" [see Cipher docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html). Then for mcrypt add PKCS#7 padding to the data to be encrypted and remove after decryption. See [PKCS padding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html)

For why not to use: [ECB mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html), scroll down to the Penguin.